# How to convert mysqli result to JSON?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have a mysqli query which I need to format as JSON for a mobile application.

I have managed to produce an XML document for the query results, however I am looking for something more lightweight. (See below for my current XML code)

```
$mysql = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');

$stmt = $mysql->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT title FROM sections ORDER BY title ASC');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);

// create xml format
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');

// create root node
$root = $doc->createElement('xml');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// add node for each row
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) : 

    $occ = $doc->createElement('data');  
    $occ = $root->appendChild($occ);  

    $child = $doc->createElement('section');  
    $child = $occ->appendChild($child);  
    $value = $doc->createTextNode($title);  
    $value = $child->appendChild($value);  

endwhile;

$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();  

header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');

// output xml jQuery ready

echo $xml_string;
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Simply create an array from the query result and then encode it

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','myDatabaseName');
$myArray = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM phase1");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

output like this:

```
[
    {"id":"31","name":"product_name1","price":"98"},
    {"id":"30","name":"product_name2","price":"23"}
]
```

If you want another style, you can change fetch_assoc() to fetch_row() and get output like this:

```
[
    ["31","product_name1","98"],
    ["30","product_name2","23"]
]
```

Comment: Use this for PHP 7.1.x to retrieve whole row as an object if you ever have to retrieve more than one column.                                                                  `while ( $row = $res->fetch_object())  {
            $myArray[ ] = $row;
        }`

Comment: @ShivaCharan ans it will get you **exactly the same** JSON as fetch_assoc

Comment: why not `json_encode($row);` directly?

Answer (score 16):

Here's how I made my JSON feed:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'myDatabaseName');
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM phase1")) {
    $tempArray = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Why do you define a new variable as $tempArray? Is $row not enough?

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned, [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) will help  you. The easiest way is to fetch your results as you already do it and build up an array that can be passed to `json_encode`.

Example:

```
$json = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  $json[]['foo'] = "your content  here";
  $json[]['bar'] = "more database results";
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Your `$json` will be a regular array with each element in it's own index.

There should be very little changed in your above code, alternativly, you can return both XML and JSON since most of the code is the same.

Comment: fetch assoc for increased pleasure.

Comment: $json[]['foo'] will create heck of a mess to handle

Answer (score 6):

There is one essential thing about JSON - the data **must** be UTF-8 encoded. Therefore, the proper encoding must be set for the database connection.

The rest is as silly as any other database operation

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT title FROM sections ORDER BY title ASC';
$data = $db->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to run this code:

```
<?php
//create an array
$emparray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
return json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add anything new to the other answers. All other answers seems to be using json_encode function

Answer (score 2):

If you have mysqlnd extension installed + enabled in php, you can use:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','myDatabaseName');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM phase1");

//Copy result into a associative array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

> mysqli::fetch_all() needs mysqlnd driver to be installed before you
>   can use it.