# Getting NULL in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I'm following this [website](http://www.techrecite.com/how-to-create-json-using-data-from-mysql-database/) to create mySQL table and php in order to convert data to JSON

SQL:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `id_employee` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_joined` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_dept` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employee`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


INSERT INTO `employee` (`id_employee`, `emp_name`, `designation`, `date_joined`, `salary`, `id_dept`) VALUES
(1, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', '2010-12-17', 2500.00, 20),
(2, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', '2005-02-20', 3500.00, 30),
(3, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', '2009-02-22', 3550.00, 30),
(4, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', '2010-04-02', 3975.00, 20),
(5, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN', '2011-09-28', 3300.00, 30);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("test_json",$db);

//Replace * in the query with the column names.
$result = mysql_query("select * from employee", $db);  

//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id_employee'] = $row['id_employee'];
    $row_array['emp_name'] = $row['emp_name'];
    $row_array['designation'] = $row['designation'];
    $row_array['date_joined'] = $row['date_joined'];
    $row_array['salary'] = $row['salary'];
    $row_array['id_dept'] = $row['id_dept'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);

//Close the database connection
fclose($db);

?>
```

However, i get 2 results with null and no other errors:

```
[{"id_employee":null,"emp_name":null,"designation":null,"date_joined":null,"salary":null,"id_dept":null},{"id_employee":null,"emp_name":null,"designation":null,"date_joined":null,"salary":null,"id_dept":null}]
```

I just copied the code and try to run it, how come there is no return in the result??

Can someone points out what's wrong with my code??

Or it is my server problem??

PHP version:5.2

MySQL ver. :5.1

Thank you

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Did you enable error reporting? If yes and you're still not getting anything, check the output of `json_last_error()`.

Comment: I would not trust any site or tutorial written in 2014 that recommends `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: what does a var dump of $json_response look like before you json_encode it?

Comment: var_dump($json_response): array(2) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id_employee"]=> NULL ["emp_name"]=> NULL ["designation"]=> NULL ["date_joined"]=> NULL ["salary"]=> NULL ["id_dept"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(6) { ["id_employee"]=> NULL ["emp_name"]=> NULL ["designation"]=> NULL ["date_joined"]=> NULL ["salary"]=> NULL ["id_dept"]=> NULL } }

Comment: It's not MySQL that's deprecated, but PHP's 'mysql_' API. So use the 'mysqli_' or 'PDO' API instead, and take best advantage of prepared statements.

Comment: Results are shown after using MySQLi, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351882/convert-mysqli-result-to-json), weird..

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset). As about JSON itself, last error can be fetched with [json_last_error()](http://php.net/json_last_error).

Answer (score 0):

You should replace mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc so you can access the variable by column name.

Also, you should start using mysqli instead of mysql, to connect and interact wth mysql database from php.

Comment: Did you use mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ?

Comment: yep.. still null. but i can get the data by using mysqli now. anyway, thanks