# how can I produce json object in php mysqli

Tags: php, json, string, mysqli

I could I produce this JSON with a MYSQLi query in PHP?

```
{
    "name": "Top Node",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Bob: Child of Top Node",
        "parent": "Top Node",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of Bob",
            "parent": "Bob: Child of Top Node"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of Bob",
            "parent": "Bob: Child of Top Node"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sally: Child of Top Node",
        "parent": "Top Node"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351882/convert-mysqli-result-to-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert mysqli result to json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351882/convert-mysqli-result-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**, to encode your result from sql query.

Example :

```
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);  //print result in json format
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i am asking about nested json to use in parent child tree.

Comment: To nested json, you need to nest query output. I mean, pass nested sql result to `rows[]`