# How would I be able to create brackets around my json file using PHP?

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

```
function get_data()
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "Database");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Furniture";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $categories = array();

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

{
        $categories[] = array(

        'mapwidth' => "2000",
        'mapheight' => "2000",


       );            
 }
```

This is what I have so far, but how would I be able to create an array of "categories" so that the json file looks like this,

```
{
    "mapwidth": "2000",
    "mapheight": "2000",
    "categories": [
    {
        "id": "furniture",
        "title": "furniture",
        "color": "#4cd3b8",
        "show": "false"
    },
    {
        "id": "rooms",
        "title": "Rooms",
        "color": "#63aa9c",
        "show": "true"
    }
    ],
```

I tried to do this but I was only able to get one row to display but am not sure how to iterate through the database so that every row will display the "id", "title", "color", and "show" within the brackets as seen in the json file. So I pretty much just want the json file to look exactly like the one shown here.

Comment: Yup, your php has some holes in there... a missing while loop... a whole missing query for the categories data... its gonna be real hard for anyone to help you with this with so many unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$employee_data = array();
$categories = array();
$employee_data["mapwidth"] ="2000";
$employee_data["mapheight"] ="2000";

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $categories[] = $row;
}
$employee_data["categories"] =$categories;
echo json_encode($employee_data);
```

Refer to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064216/6281135) to further improve your code.

Comment: Thanks!!! Where would I put the data in to fill the array of categories?

Comment: they are populated from your $result inside the loop.

Comment: hmm im not getting anything returned inside categories.

Comment: Got it! just changed it to this                                                            
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            $categories[] = $row; Thanks!