# What's the best way to return a SQL query response from PHP to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I'm creating a Google Map page to show the nearest people to a provided centre point. I send the centre coords via fetch to my server php, perform the mysql query and get the response back (name, lat, long, website-url, distance).
Is it possible to send the SQL response back as some sort of JSON object, or something like that, which can be used directly in the javascript, or do I have to stringify as csv data and then parse in the javascript side to recreate the object there? Or is there a better, alternative approach I should have considered?

Comment: `Is it possible to send the SQL response back as some sort of JSON object`...yes. json_encode on the php side, JSON.parse on the JavaScript side

Comment: [PHP json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) and [JS JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351882/how-to-convert-mysqli-result-to-json

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have had a successful day with your advice.